# Change settings like 'limit selection to visible' or 'trackball rotation' with python

Tags: python, interface, customization

My original intention is to transfer settings with a .blend file, but as far as I know, ordinary blends don't store everything.

I have tried to understand the API documentation for a while now, yet since I'm not a developer, I have a hard time closing the 'assumed knowledge' gap.

So far I've found [`bpy.types.SpaceView3D.use_occlude_geometry`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_release/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.use_occlude_geometry) but no sample code or link and I just get error messages.

Blender's *Info* window output isn't revealing much either when I push the button manually, at least not to the untrained eye.
`bpy.data.screens["Default"].(null) = False`

So, here are my needs:

- Switch <kbd>MMB</kbd> with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>MMB</kbd>
- Turn on *trackball rotation* for viewport rotation
- Disable *Limit selection to visible*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Switch <kbd>MMB</kbd> with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>MMB</kbd>

  ```
  view3d_km = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs['Blender'].keymaps['3D View']
  view3d_km.keymap_items['view3d.rotate'].map_type = 'MOUSE'
  view3d_km.keymap_items['view3d.rotate'].type = 'MIDDLEMOUSE'
  view3d_km.keymap_items['view3d.rotate'].shift = True
  ```
- Turn on *trackball rotation* for <kbd>MMB</kbd>

  ```
  bpy.context.user_preferences.inputs.view_rotate_method = 'TRACKBALL'
  ```
- Disable *Limit selection to visible*

  ```
  for scr in bpy.data.screens:
      for area in scr.areas:
          for space in area.spaces:
              if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                  space.use_occlude_geometry = True
  ```

Comment: This really helps. It seems to be enough to change the .shift values of view3D.rotate and view3d.move

Comment: Yep - if it's already set up to use middlemouse, which it usually will be.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure on the first one (you want to swap rotate with pan?) but...

Turn on trackball rotation:

```
bpy.context.user_preferences.inputs.view_rotate_method = 'TRACKBALL'
```

Disable *Limit selection to visible* in all 3D Views in all screens:

```
for screen in bpy.data.screens:
    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            area.spaces[0].use_occlude_geometry = False
```

Comment: Since Gimp and basically all 2D areas in Blender use MMB to pan, and since I pan more than I rotate and because it once was a simple toggle button in Blender, I use MMB to pan in the 3D view. My muscle memory likes it.

Comment: This is a great example how four lines of code give me a clear picture instantly. Thank you